# Scalaz optionT transfomer seems to fail with type alias

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, scalaz

It seems that using type aliases confuses the Scala type inferencer or the compiler. Indeed trying to compile

```
import scalaz.OptionT.optionT
type Foo[A] = Option[Option[A]]
val x: Foo[Int] = Some(Some(3))
optionT(x)
```

results in the strange error

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: transpose requires all collections have the same size
```

Due to my limited experience with Scala, I am not sure whether I should file a bug for this, ot if this is the expected behaviour.

> Is this really a bug or the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having just tested that myself that IllegalArgumentException is the compiler bailing out, which would be a bug.

Answer (score 1):

I also tested this and it really seems like a bug, you should report that to the scala team. You can however fix this, by giving the compiler a hint:

```
val x: Foo[Int] = Some(Some(4))
val y = optionT[Option](x)
y: scalaz.OptionT[Option,Int] = OptionT(Some(Some(3)))
```